# Is there a benefit to using $1 over a Template Literal with pg-promise queries?

Tags: postgresql, pg-promise

Using [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), is there any benefit to using `$1` over Template Literals? Template Literals are just much more familiar to me, but I have to assume they do it differently for a reason with this package.

**The "Normal" Way:**

```
db.any('SELECT * FROM users WHERE active = $1', [true])
```

**The Way I did it:**

```
const isTrue = true;

db.any(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE active = ${isTrue}`)
```

**UPDATED The Way I did it:**

```
const isTrue = true;
const name = 'Matt'
db.any('SELECT * FROM users WHERE active = $1 AND name = $2', [isTrue, name])
```

**OR**

```
const isTrue = true;
const name = 'Matt'
db.any(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE active = $/isTrue/ AND name = $/name/`, {isTrue, name})
```

Comment: Sooner or later you'll meet [Little Bobby Tables](https://bobby-tables.com) and you'll have a massive mess to clean up let alone dangerously bad habits to unlearn.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit. I get the reference to SQL Injection but not the connection to the above.

Comment: (1) String interpolation for SQL is a terrible habit. (2) Different databases use different representations for booleans so again string interpolation is a bad habit. (3) If you use string interpolation for a boolean then you'll end up using it for a string and then you're open to injection, bad habits etc. (4) I don't mean to sound harsh but it is 2019 and this was a bad practice 20 years ago. This is such an easy problem to solve correctly and safely, there's no excuse whatsoever for opting for "familiar" over "correct".

Comment: @mu is too short Apologies, I'm still learning SQL. 

So Using the $1 for variables is safe. See the example above and let me know if that is better. I guess I'm ufzzy on, am I not supposed to use variables period? or is this fine? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @MattWeber Both `Index Variables` and `Named Parameters` are safe. You weren't using either of those. Instead, you were using ES6 literals, exposing yourself to invalid value formatting + SQL injection.

Comment: So the new methods posted in the updated version are both good? Correct? Thank you again

Comment: Yes, as it was already shown in my answer.

Comment: Using numbered placeholders (`$1`, `$2`, ...) is safe because those will be handled by PostgreSQL itself (i.e. the SQL with placeholders and the values for those placeholders are sent to the database separately). The named placeholders (`$/isTrue/`, `$/name/`, ...) should also be safe.

Comment: @muistooshort Not in this case. Syntax `$1, $2` is also handled by pg-promise, extended with many extra features, as documented by the [Formatting Filters](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#formatting-filters). Only [Parameterized Queries](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/ParameterizedQuery.html) and [Prepared Statements](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/PreparedStatement.html) are formatted on the server side.

Comment: @vitaly-t Thanks, I guess you'd be the one to know ;) But they're still safe because they use proper quoting/escaping and that's the important part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> is there any benefit to using $1 over Template Literals?

You cannot use Template Literals, which [documentation emphasizes](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#named-parameters):

> **IMPORTANT:** Never use the reserved `${}` syntax inside ES6 template strings, as those have no knowledge of how to format values for PostgreSQL. Inside ES6 template strings you can only use one of the 4 alternatives - `$()`, `$<>`, `$[]` or `$//`.

You should use [Named Parameters](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#named-parameters), they offer a lot of benefits over the [Index Variables](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#index-variables):

- Support for [nested names](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#nested-named-parameters)
- Support for `this` reference
- Much easier to read and maintain inside [SQL files](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#query-files)

For your own example, if you really need Template Strings there:

```js
const isTrue = true;

await db.any(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE active = $/isTrue/`, {isTrue});
```

or you can just use the standard strings:

```js
await db.any('SELECT * FROM users WHERE active = ${isTrue}', {isTrue});
```